# Generate random grammar expansions in TatSu (Python)

Tags: random, grammar, expansion, tatsu

I'm writing an interpreter for a grammar parser generated with TatSu. I'm looking for a convenient way to generate use cases for my grammar, so I can write unit tests for my interpreter. Currently, I'm generating my test cases by hand.

I wonder if the TatSu package does provide any (maybe undocumented) means to auto-generate random grammar derivations so I could use them as test cases for my interpreter. In addition, it would be desirable to specify the grammar rule, for which I need the random productions.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for random input generated from the grammar (derivations)? Random productions sounds very strange.

Comment: Yes, sorry, like in the title, I'm looking for "expansions" (=derivations), not to be confused with grammar productions (rules).

Comment: A way to solve my problem would be to implement a TatSu semantics class for a TatSu parser compiled with its own TatSu grammar that would generate collections of all option, choice, and sequence rules, as well as terminals in a given grammar. Such a class could then be used for a random generation of derivations of a given grammar. I'm asking myself if there are internals in the existing TatSu package (5.6.1) that provide these collections already.

Comment: So first, amend your question so it says "derivations". After that, there are languages that derive languages that are infinite. But I have some ideas about how to generate some derivations in a minimal way.

Comment: I amended the question as you wished. I think the TatSu internals I was looking for is the structure of the "rulemap" object in a compiled parser. I also have already ideas on how to utilize it for my purpose and I'm working already on a proof of concept. If it works, I will post it as a possible answer. Yes, infinite derivations are possible, and the algorithm would need some strategies to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `__str__()` method in `grammars.py` you'll see an example of walking through a grammar to transform it into something readable.

You could also use a `Visitor`.

Because the set of derivations for a grammar is potentially infinite, you need a strategy to generate some interesting samples before quitting (`Ctrl-C`):

- go breadth-first, or the visitor will recurse until the runtime stack is exhausted
- because of PEG, work first with the *last* option in a choice (`|`), which should be the one producing the shortest derivation

Because TatSu skips over whitespace, you'll probably need to add a step to pretty-print the output.

This is an interesting project, and it would be good if at the end you added it as a pull request to TatSu.

My apologies for providing only guidelines instead of an example.

Comment: Thx, I've started working on a solution based on the rulemap attribute of a compiled tatsu parser. I appreciate your suggestion about using the last option in a choice. If I succeed. I will create a pull request. There is a 'grammars.py' in the tatsu package, but no 'grammar.py'. Its __str__() method is probably not the one you mean.

Comment: It is indeed `tatsu/grammars.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an experimental public repository [TatSu Random Derivation Generator](https://github.com/bookofproofs/TatSuRDG) that can generate random derivations for many rules of your grammars compiled with TatSu. If the grammars are very complex, the program runs into a RecursionError.

Nevertheless, it is useful for testing your grammars, especially if you want to test derivations for specific production rules.

The `example.py` as well as the many tests show you how to use the tool.